# Xcode Swift 2.0 Multiple Annotation on Mkmapview by using JSON

Tags: xcode, swift, annotations, location, mkmapview

Recently I tried to put multiple annotation in a single mapview, I used JSON to fill up my location latitude and longitude. I'm facing some problem about how to link JSON file and able to show multiple annotation on my mapview?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let map = MKMapView(frame: view.bounds)
    map.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
    view.addSubview(map)

    var annotations = NSMutableArray()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        let pointData = NSData(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("location", ofType: "geojson")!)
        let points = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(pointData!,
            options: nil,
            error: nil) as NSDictionary
        for point in points["features"] as NSArray {
            let coordinate = (point["geometry"] as NSDictionary)["coordinates"] as NSArray
            let lon = coordinate[0] as CLLocationDegrees
            let lat = coordinate[1] as CLLocationDegrees
            let a = MKPointAnnotation()
            a.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
            annotations.addObject(a)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            map.addAnnotations(annotations)
            map.showAnnotations(map.annotations, animated: false)
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: can add more details to your question to get help

Comment: let points = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(pointData!, (Showing error argument in call) When i try to put in in swift 2.0 this error show up